# How to detect if a URL has an image file or not?

Tags: java, image, android-studio, url, android-glide

**Problem:**

I am using the Glide library in Android Studio to load images in an imageview that are from a url, the problem would be that there are times that the url does not have any image, that is, the url exists, but it does not contain any image. For example:

**1) This url  contains an image:**

https://static.hogarmania.com/archivos/201210/merienda-321x171x80xX.jpg

**2) But this url not contains an image**

https://www.petitchef.es/imgupl/recipe/md-155916p233026.jpg

**Question:**

Is there any way so that before loading the image with the Glide library, I can verify if the url I receive contains or does not contain an image?

Comment: Given that both url have `.jpg` in the link but one doesn't contain an image, then no, how will you know without loading the link contents first? Otherwise do a sanitary check on the data (for 404 or other errors) before calling your glide library.

Comment: Execute a HEAD command and look at the `Content-type` response header.

Comment: There's no in-built mechanism within Glide for your scenario. You will have to handle it manually.

Comment: The resource referred to by the second URL does *not* exist.

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: You have to check the URL response. You may refer to the code below. Refer the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/net/HttpURLConnection).

```
URL u = new URL ( "http://www.example.com/");
HttpURLConnection hUC =  ( HttpURLConnection )  u.openConnection (); 
hUC.setRequestMethod ("GET");  //OR  hUC.setRequestMethod ("HEAD"); 
hUC.connect () ; 
int code = hUC.getResponseCode() ;
System.out.println(code);
```

- Step 2: Check if it is an image with the code below.

```
URLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = new URL(imageURL).openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
boolean img = contentType.startsWith("image/"); // if img is true then it is an image
```

- You can also add ***placeholder*** to the imageview with the help of Glide. You can check out about placeholders [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html).

Comment: This fetches the resource, which was specifically not wanted, and does not tell whether it was an image, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Both the links provided in the question were images, but the server was not ready to handle the request in one of them. One has to check if the link is active or not before checking if it was an image. Nevertheless, I will edit my answer.

Comment: One can check whether the 'link is active' and whether it's an image at the same time. You don't need two `URL`s, two `HttpURLConnections`, and two HTTP request/response cycles. And one of the links did not exist at all: it got a 404 Not Found. Nothing to do with the server not being 'ready to handle the request'..